# React Router not recognizing auth token (AAD B2C) in incognito

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, incognito-mode

I'm using the [react-azure-adb2c](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-azure-adb2c) package to authenticate users in my web app. I have a `react-router-dom` Route set up to require authentication:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import authentication from 'react-azure-adb2c';
import Home from '../Home';
import Products from '../Products';

authentication.initialize({
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/',
  tenant: process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_DOMAIN,
  signInPolicy: process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_POLICY_ID,
  applicationId: process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_CLIENT_ID,
  scopes: [process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_SCOPES],
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_URL,
  postLogoutRedirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_URL,
});

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/products"
          component={authentication.required(Products)}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This works as expected in a normal browser window, the user clicks a link to `/products`, gets redirected to an Azure AD B2C login page, gets pushed back to the app on login, and then redirected to `/products`.

But in an incognito browser, when the user gets pushed back to the app after login, they get redirected back to the Azure login page a second time. If they log in again with the second prompt, then they get pushed to `/products`, as they should have the first time.

My guess here is that the Router is trying to redirect the user to the authenticated Route before the app is recognizing the token, but I'm not really sure. Again, this is only happening in an incognito browser.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe if you change the cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage' to 'localStorage' it will work. Maybe some information needed by azure ad b2c is being saved there and then on the redirect its getting deleted. Just a guess.

Comment: Appreciate it! I have already tried that with the same thoughts in mind you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is because as incognito / private browsing windows will not retain local / session storage.

> You can use localStorage in Chrome and Firefox, however private storage is independent from non-private/private windows, i.e. setting an item in private mode will not reflect back into non-private mode.

> Local Storage data stored on normal browsing sessions will not be available when you open a browser in private browsing or in Incognito mode.

**MDN Reference:**

> When private browsing mode is enabled, temporary, databases are created to be used for cookies and local storage; these databases are thrown away when private browsing mode is turned off, and the regular databases are re-activated. The temporary cookie and local storage databases start out empty.
> [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Supporting_private_browsing_mode).

Comment: I should have clarified, this happens regardless of the stage I enter the app at. I can recreate this scenario every time I login in incognito, it's not just when I switch over from a normal browser. The session is the same so locaStorage is not getting thrown away.

Comment: it seems that the storage is not ready on this first time and once the user redirected second time the application is able to access the storage.

Comment: You could check if the storage is ready or not and of not ready then reload  the page with some interval.